# Styling Text Within a Cell in Google Spreadsheets

Tags: google-sheets

In Excel it is possible to style text within a cell, by pressing <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.
You can create for example the following sequence: **1**,*2*,***3***,4.

Is that possible in Google Spreadsheets?

Comment: Related: [Script to change individual text color within a cell](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/87202/88163)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of quite recently (02-09-2015) it is possible in Google Spreadsheets to have partial formatting within a cell.

### Quote

> Partial cell formatting in Sheets When it comes to spreadsheets—and
>   the cells that comprise them—we know that one size doesn’t always fit
>   all. That’s why it’s now possible to select only a portion of the
>   characters within a cell in Sheets and to apply text formatting to
>   only those characters (as opposed to the entire cell). This
>   functionality is available on the web and in the Sheets Android app.

### Screenshot

[image]

### Note

It might take a while for the feature to be available as it's being rolled out.

### Reference

- http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.nl/2015/09/do-your-best-work-with-google-docs.html

Answer (score 2):

Even though this looks to be a pretty old version of a Google Apps training module, the answer remains the same. No, you can't apply multiple formatting options to a single cell in Google Spreadsheets:

http://edutraining.googleapps.com/Training-Home/module-4-docs/chapter-4/5-5

> Formatting is performed on only a complete cell. It is not possible to
>   format only parts of a cell (for example, bolding one word in the
>   cell).